# How to generate libcurl.so.5 with curl 7.56.1 in Yocto?

Tags: curl, libcurl, yocto, openembedded

I have builded previously libcurl.so.5 when I compile curl 7.53.1
Now when I compile curl 7.56.1 the generated librarie is: libcurl.so.4.5 , how can I define the version to build?

Comment: It's hard to answer for this question because You are not "telling" how You are switch between two version of recipes between builds - or You manually changed PV of recipe or You are making copy of main recipe with newer release - I think it's important to provide more details how You are create newwer version of recipe.

Comment: I have removed the recipe for 7.53.1 and included the new one for 7.56.1

Answer (score 1):

The X in libcurl.so.X is [ABI version](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/abi.html), i.e. version that defines compatibility between application and library. So, you cannot just select whatever you wish to have as it depends on library API and its implementation in library sources. So, you either should rebuild all dependent components (and make them support it) on newer version or set preferred version of curl in local config (or custom distro config):

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_curl = "A.B.C"
```

which corresponds to the desired version of libcurl.